# Why does Extension Manager take a lot of time to open in Brackets?

Tags: software-installation, extension, adobe-brackets

I just don't understand what to do without extension manager
It would make my work very easy if it works.

You can search for and install/uninstall extensions using *File* -> *Extension Manager* (or click the "plugin block" icon on the toolbar). You can even temporarily disable extensions and re-enable them later from the Extension Manager.

[image: Extension Manager]

Comment: Slow down there, friend. Exactly which extension manager are you trying to describe a problem with? And on which release of Ubuntu? How can any of us reproduce the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I have experienced the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04, and I also noticed that my CPU usage spiked at the same time that I was experiencing this problem. Extension Manager caused brackets to hang, and Brackets had to be force closed from the System Monitor. Otherwise Brackets works normally. This behavior could be a bug in Brackets.

Comment: The solution is to change  the language under `Debug -> Switch Language` from `system default` to `English(US)`. Found it [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/13730#issuecomment-415365488).

Comment: @Jignesh 's solution works for me. Thanks.